# Sum different values efficiently

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I got an array containing objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 91,
    "factor": 2,
    "title": "Test Product",
    "price": 50,
    "interval": 1,
    "setup": 0,
    "optional": false
  },
  {
    "id": 92,
    "factor": 1,
    "title": "Another Test Product",
    "price": 95,
    "interval": 1,
    "setup": 99,
    "optional": true
  },
  {
    "id": 93,
    "factor": 1,
    "title": "Just Another Test Product",
    "price": 12,
    "interval": 1,
    "setup": 0,
    "optional": false
  }
]
```

Alright - now I'd like to create a sum for:

- Setup (total)
- Price (total)
- Price for all products by interval (group by 1,2,3,4, ...)

For now I am using computed values for each task:

```
setupTotal: function () {
            return this.products.reduce ((acc, product) => acc + (parseFloat (product.setup) * parseFloat (product.factor)), 0);
        },
```

and

```
monthlyCostsTotal: function () {
            let sum = 0;
            this.products.forEach (function (product) {
                if (product.interval == 1) {
                    sum += (parseFloat (product.price) * parseFloat (product.factor));
                }
            });
            return sum;
        },
```

and

```
setupOptional: function () {
    let sum = 0;
    this.products.forEach (function (product) {
        if (product.optional) {
            sum += (parseFloat (product.setup) * parseFloat (product.factor));
        }
    });

    return sum;
},
```

But of course this is not the optimum, because I am looping through the array over and over again.

So my question: How can I create a more efficient way to sum values by:

- Price total
- Price (only optional)
- Setup total
- Setup (only optional)
- Price by interval

Comment: why do you use `parseFloat` for numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object and sum as required.

```js
var data = [{ id: 91, factor: 2, title: "Test Product", price: 50, interval: 1, setup: 0, optional: false }, { id: 92, factor: 1, title: "Another Test Product", price: 95, interval: 1, setup: 99, optional: true }, { id: 93, factor: 1, title: "Just Another Test Product", price: 12, interval: 1, setup: 0, optional: false }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { factor, price, interval, setup, optional }) => {
        r.price += factor * price;
        r.setup += factor * setup;
        if (optional) {
            r.price_optional += factor * price;
            r.setup_optional += factor * setup;
        }
        r.interval[interval] = (r.interval[interval] || 0) + factor * price;
        return r;
    }, { price: 0, price_optional: 0, setup: 0, setup_optional: 0, interval: {} });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one computed function and return an object containing the results :

```
calcPrice: function () {
    let optional_sum = 0;
    let interval_sum = 0;
    this.products.forEach (function (product) {

        if (product.optional) {
            optional_sum += (parseFloat (product.setup) * parseFloat (product.factor));
        }

         if (product.interval == 1) {
             interval_sum += (parseFloat (product.price) * parseFloat (product.factor));
         }
    });

    return {
         optional : optional_sum ,
         interval : interval_sum
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like: `calcPrice.optional` OR `calcPrice.interval`

Hope you get the idea.